# How to center a select box in a cell table using HTML?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

This may seem silly, but I'm a beginner here and I can't wrap my head around this one:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santosonit/1027uLrj/#&togetherjs=dFbjbJhBTL)

```
<table class="table table-sm table-striped" id="dtable" style="font-size:0.9em">
  <thead style="white-space: nowrap">
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 17%" class="text-center">Link To File</th>
      <th style="width: 18%" class="text-center">Approval Status</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;min-width: 160px;max-width: 160px;text-align:center">2</td>
        <td class="align-middle" style="align-center">
          <select name="D1" style="border-radius: 0.2rem">
            <option value="empty"></option>
            <option value="approved">Approved</option>
            <option value="dicsuss">Discuss</option>
            <option value="cancelled">Cancelled</option>
           </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

It should look like this:
[image]
Appreciate any help.

Comment: are you using bootstrap? where do you define  table-sm table-striped ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using bootstrap

Change this:

```
          <td class="text-center">
          <select class="text-center" name="D1" style="border-radius: 0.2rem">
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table table-sm table-striped" id="dtable" style="font-size:0.9em">
  <thead style="white-space: nowrap">
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 17%" class="text-center">Link To File</th>
      <th style="width: 18%" class="text-center">Approval Status</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="align-middle" style="word-wrap: break-word;min-width: 160px;max-width: 160px;text-align:center">2</td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <select class="text-center" name="D1" style="border-radius: 0.2rem">
            <option value="empty"></option>
            <option value="approved">Approved</option>
            <option value="dicsuss">Discuss</option>
            <option value="cancelled">Cancelled</option>
           </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, which clearly works above. However, when applying this to my case, the select box is not aligned vertically, but rather on the top. Appreciate your time! Thank you!